# Jquery UI dialog Close button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I used jquery UI dialog like the following image.

[image: jquery UI dialog]

When i click the print button then the content of a div inside the dialog will be printed.

Code of Print function

```
function printDiv() {
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML; 
    var printContents = document.getElementById('PrintDivcontent').innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>"
            + printContents + "</body>";
    window.print(); 
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

The print functionality works fine. But after printing the content by clicking the Print button, the close button of the dialog is not working. When i click the close button before clicking the Print it will work.
In console the following error is displayed

```
TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined
.data( widgetFullName )._focusTabbable();
```

Any work around for this?
Please help me.

**UPDATED**

HTML Code

```
<div id="ReportPopup">
            <div id="PrintDivcontent">

                <div id="ReportTablecontainer">
                    <table id="ReportTable"><tbody><tr><th>Time</th><th>Action</th><th>comment</th></tr><tr class=""><td style="text-align:center;width:25%">2014-06-05 13:50:03</td><td style="padding-left:5px;width:50%">cdfsdfsd</td><td style="text-align:center;width:25%"></td></tr><tr class="altRow"><td style="text-align:center;width:25%">2014-06-05 13:51:58</td><td style="padding-left:5px;width:50%">fsdfsd</td><td style="text-align:center;width:25%">dsfsd</td></tr><tr class=""><td style="text-align:center;width:25%">2014-06-05 13:52:01</td><td style="padding-left:5px;width:50%">dfsdfs</td><td style="text-align:center;width:25%">sfsdfs</td></tr><tr class="altRow"><td style="text-align:center;width:25%">2014-06-05 14:25:45</td><td style="padding-left:5px;width:50%">dsfsdfs</td><td style="text-align:center;width:25%">sdfsdfsd</td></tr><tr class=""><td style="text-align:center;width:25%">2014-06-05 14:42:10</td><td style="padding-left:5px;width:50%">sdfsdfsd</td><td style="text-align:center;width:25%">sdfsdfsd</td></tr></tbody></table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="reportButtonContainer">

                <input type="button" onclick="printDiv()"  value="PRINT">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Dialog

```
$("#ReportPopup").dialog({
            modal:true,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Report',           
            show:  {
                effect      : 'fold'
            },
            hide:{
                effect : 'fold'
            },
            width: 650,
            height: 600 ,
            minHeight:"auto"
        });
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide the HTML code associated with it, so that I can complete the Fiddle. Thanks

Comment: JSFiddle is down please wait for sometime

Comment: please post demo in the fiddle

Comment: Hi , I have checked its working , please check the link http://jsbin.com/bidipivu/1/edit

Comment: @subhkriti not working for me...

Comment: @subhkriti close button works before clicking the print button. After clicking print button close button is not working

Comment: I think this is due to the print functionality . When i use only window.print() inside the printDiv function it will works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code for print functionality.

```
function printDiv() {  
      var divContents = $("#PrintDivcontent").html();
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=800');
        printWindow.document
                .write('<html><head><title>Title of Print Page</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write(divContents);

        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();

    }
```

Now it works fine.
[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/bidipivu/4/edit)

Comment: Hi, Could you please check the Demo Link again, I think now Print Dialog of Windows not getting up.